# Display MySQL Query Results from Perl Script

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

My Perl script is supposed to print the results from my query. However, at the moment I'm getting the error:

`Can't locate object method "fetchrow_array" via package "SELECT * FROM SERVER" (perhaps you forgot to load "SELECT * FROM SERVER"?) at updateDB.pl line 32`

I imagine the problem is an easy one to fix.. but my perl / MySQL skills have much to be desired. My script is below:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

use strict;
use warnings;

MySQL("SELECT * FROM SERVER");

# define subroutine to submit MySQL command
sub MySQL
{
    # establish connection with 'serverDNA' database
    my $connection = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=serverDNA;host=localhost");

    my $query = $_[0];  #assign argument to string

    my $statement = $connection->prepare($query);   #prepare query

    $statement->execute();   #execute query

    #loop to print MySQL results
    while (my @row = $query->fetchrow_array)
    {
            print "@row\n";
    }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: try changing $query->fetchrow_array to $statement->fetchrow_array

Comment: There are a few things you should consider when working with DBI. You don't need to `use` the DBD in this case, DBI will load it automatically for you. The DBI doc says it's best practice to name your connection handler `$dbh` and your statement handlers `$sth`. I also suggest you read up on the DBI doc regarding different types of `fetch`, and what `prepare` does. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `fetchrow_array` on the query string; you want to call it on the statement.

```
while (my @row = $statement->fetchrow_array)
{
  print "@row\n";
}
```